# Avoid page break between paragraphs

Tags: page-breaking

This script:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
Examples:
\\\nopagebreak
example 1\\
example 2\\
example 3
\end{document}
```

unfortunately introduces an awkward page break between "Examples:" and "example 1":

[image]

I attempt to tackle the problem by using `\nopagebreak` however, my solution doesn't work. How to fix?

Comment: the `\nopagebreak` in that position is preventing a break between example1 and example2, but you should not need such a command in-document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not "between paragraphs" that is a single paragraph (`\\` never ends a paragraph).

Do not use `\\` and use a section heading like `\section*{Examples}` latex does not allow page breaks after a section heading

Comment: \section does not seem right here as it has a specific formatting and goes to TOC. Can I use `\par` instead of `\\`?

Comment: `\section*` doesn't go in the toc by default and has user or class defined formatting so you can make it use whatever format you want. You almost never need to use `\par` in a document as it  is a simpler (and equivalent) to simply leave a blank line.

Comment: `\section*` does not go to the ToC.